# How to disable SWT event listening if the action is not triggered by user

Tags: java, event-handling, events, swt

I notice that the ModifyListener will be triggered regardless the action is caused by user or system itself, for instance,

```
Text t = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
t.addModifyListener(new TModifyListener());
```

...............................................

```
private class TModifyListener implements ModifyListener
{

    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event)
    {

        Text text = (Text) event.widget;
        t.setText(process(text.getText()));
    }
}
```

This will cause infinite loop and crash the program. Do you guys have any idea how to disable the event listening if the event is generated by system, and enable it if the event is caused by user?

Comment: Of course this will blow your stack.  Why would you write this code? What are you trying to accomplish?  Is it a model to UI binding problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to implement Presentation-Model architecture my own, in particular, I try to implement auto-correct feature like what we have in MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just set a ThreadLocal in your listener and check it when it's re-entered?

edit: In fact it wouldn't even need to be a ThreadLocal, since SWT is single-threaded.  Just set a boolean field on the listener.

```
private class TModifyListener implements ModifyListener {

    private boolean _setting;

    @Override
    public void modifyText(ModifyEvent event)
    {
            if(!_setting) {
                _setting = true;
                try {
                    Text text = (Text) event.widget;
                    t.setText(process(text.getText()));
                } finally {
                    _setting = false;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method works provided the event broadcasting is run in sequential fashion. What I afraid is the event broadcasting may run in async / concurrent fashion. That might cause problem.

Comment: You can make the body of `_setting` contained in a `synchronized` to avert this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know swt but...

If `process` is idempotent then perhaps you could `setText` only if it is different from `getText`

Another option is to set some property on the widget in the first callback which you can query, unset and not call `setText` in the second callback.